# Export database from SQLitestudio to SQL format

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, export

I am using SQLiteStudio (v2.1.2) to create a database, when I tried to export my database after creating it and fill it with data I get strange error:

```
     can't read "tableDdl(part)": no such element in array
    while executing
"regexp -- {(?i)^\s*CREATE\s+VIRTUAL.*} $tableDdl($lower)"
    (object "::.exportTable" method "::ExportDialog::sortTablesByFk" body line 20)
    invoked from within
"sortTablesByFk $db $tablesToExport"
    (object "::.exportTable" method "::ExportDialog::exportDatabase" body line 51)
    invoked from within
"exportDatabase $db"
    (object "::.exportTable" method "::ExportDialog::okClicked" body line 109)
    invoked from within
"okClicked"
    (object "::.exportTable" method "::Modal::clicked" body line 9)
    invoked from within
"::.exportTable clicked ok"
    invoked from within
".exportTable.f.btn.export invoke "
    invoked from within
".exportTable.f.btn.export instate !disabled { .exportTable.f.btn.export invoke } "
    invoked from within
".exportTable.f.btn.export instate pressed { .exportTable.f.btn.export state !pressed; .exportTable.f.btn.export instate !disabled { .exportTable.f.btn..."
    (command bound to event)
```

Did I miss something ?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in SQLiteStudio. First thing to try is to update to newest version (2.1.4). If this one fails too, then I'd suggest you to go with this to forum (http://forum.sqlitestudio.pl), so it can be worked out.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: How this is not an answer? He asked if he misses something, so I said he's not missing anything and it's is more of the SQLiteStudio's problem, than his.
To be clear on this - I do know that this is a bug in SQLiteStudio. Question is if it's only in version 2.1.2 or also the newest (2.1.4) is affected too.

Comment: Thanks @Googie it is obviously a version issue , I upgrade it to 2.1.4 and it works fine.